# HTML Table not being populated

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I'm facing an odd situation with something extremely simple.

The information is not being populated from the DB to the HTML table. The DB is a MySQL and I'm using PHP to connect and get the information.

The connection is answer as "Success!" so I can not see a reason for this issue.

MY CODE:

```
    connector1.php:

    <?php

    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    $database = "PERFBASE";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

    if($mysqli->connect_errno)
    echo "Connection to DB Failed: (".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error;
    else echo "Success!";


    -------------------------------------------------------------------------


    index.php

    <?php
    include("connector1.php");

    $consulta = sprintf("SELECT * FROM PERFTRIG");


    $con = $mysqli -> query($consulta) or die($mysqli -> error);

    $SYSNAME = "SYSNAME";


    ?>


    <html>

    <body>
    <table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
     <th>System</th>
     <th>Client</th>
     <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array())?>
    <td><?php echo $dado[$SYSNAME]; ?></td>
   <td>Ozzy</td>
  <td>17/09/22</td>
   </tr>
   </table>

   </body>
    </html>
```

This is a query directly in the MYSQL:

```
    MariaDB [PERFBASE]> describe PERFTRIG
        -> ;
    +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | SYSID        | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | DATETIME     | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | SYSNAME      | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | ACCOUNTL     | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Do you have any idea about what is happening?

Comment: your `while` loop is never closed, try surrounding the code that should be looped within curly braces `{ }`

Comment: Your while loop has no `{` opening and closing `}`
`<?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()) { ?>
<td><?php echo $dado[$SYSNAME]; } ?></td>`

Comment: I'd look at `$consulta = sprintf("SELECT * FROM PERFTRIG");` What is the value of the output if after that line you add `var_dump($consulta);` Have you enabled sane error reporting levels and been checking displayed errors or logs? Seeing numerous syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

William Perron, ficuscr, RamaKrishna - Thank you very much dudes!!!

Final Answer after fixing according to your clarification:

```
    <body>
    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
    <th>System</th>
    <th>Client</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($dado = $conn->fetch_array()): ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $dado[$SYSNAME]; ?></td>
    <td>Ozzy</td>
    <td>17/09/22</td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>

    </body>
```

Its working just fine now!

Answer (score 2):

Replace this part:

```
<?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array())?>
<td><?php echo $dado[$SYSNAME]; ?></td>
```

with that:

```
<?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()) { ?> // loop start here
<td><?php echo $dado[$SYSNAME]; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Its hard logic for php and you need to be correct with sintax.
And I think that you don't need next one (whats the point of this?):

```
$consulta = sprintf("SELECT * FROM PERFTRIG");
```

Just use in you code:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM PERFTRIG";
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you doing mistake with while loop you missing curly braces

Try this way.

```
    <tr>
     <?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()): ?> // dont forget colon
     <td><?php echo $dado[$SYSNAME]; ?></td>
     <td>Ozzy</td>
     <td>17/09/22</td>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Can I get an `endwhile`?

Comment: yes you can do other way also 
`<?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()) : ?>
   // do stuff inside here 
<?php endwhile; ?>`

Comment: And then you don't do what @petya did below, placing curly bracket in wrong direction :) Much easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: @ficuscr sure man will improve but i was writing petya already answered .